# How to establish join and self join on the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, join

The situation is like this:

1. There is `Teacher Performance` and `Student Performance` entity, so teacher and student may attend same course have their score
2. Teacher can teach student and teacher
3. There is a `Teaching Relation` table, and yes both teacher and student can appear in attendance column, but only teacher can appear in teacher column.
4. The desired report table is list all teacher's performance, plus average performance of the students and teachers who are taught by the teacher.

In our system the id is numeric, I made it first name just for demo purpose.

Teacher Performance(tb_tp)

```
t_id       | score
------------------
 JOHN      | 5
 ASHLEY    | 6
 STEVEN    |4.5
```

Student Performance(tb_sp)

```
      s_id | score
------------------
 SCOTT     | 5
 FRANK     | 8
 TIM       | 7
```

Teaching Relation(tb_tr)

```
 t_id (teacher) | a_id for attendance id | a_type attendance type
------------------------------------------------------------------
 ASHLEY         | JOHN                   | teacher
 ASHLEY         | FRANK                  | student
 ASHLEY         | TIM                    | student
 JOHN           | ASHLEY                 | teacher
 JOHN           | FRANK                  | student
```

Desired Report:

```
   t_id     | Score| avg_t  AVG score from Teacher | avg_s AVG score from Student
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ASHLEY   |   6  |     (5 from John) /1          | (8 from Frank + 7 from Tim)/2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   JOHN     |   5  |   (6 from ASHLEY) /1          | (8 from Frank) / 1
```

How can we make this happen? I am thinking two joins together or union two queries, but either way cannot keep the result on the same row and be accurate

Comment: Why are you using their first name as the identifier...?  This seems like a very poor database design - what if you had two teachers named Scott, or a teacher and a student named John?

Comment: @Siyual we do use id, but just for demo purpose I make it first name...

Comment: Please use your actual structure in the question then...  Making it the first name instead of an ID is just confusing.

Comment: How are you differentiating between a teacher and a student in the Teaching Relation table?  How do we know that the ID is for a student rather than a teacher?

Comment: @Siyual Just updated, actual world the student id and teacher id will never be the same because of different id format, but I add the attendance type column to differentiate, also add table headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the technique you want is two outer joins with an aggregate.  Here is my untested pass at it:

```
SELECT p.t_id, p.score, scores.avg_teacher_score, scores.avg_student_score
FROM teacher_performance p
JOIN (
  SELECT t_id, AVG( t.score) AS avg_teacher_score, AVG( s.score ) AS avg_student_score
  FROM teaching_relation tr
  LEFT JOIN teacher_performance t ON t.t_id = tr.a_id AND tr.a_type='teacher'
  LEFT JOIN student_performance s ON s.s_id = tr.a_id AND tr.a_type='student'
  ) scores
  ON scores.t_id = p.t_id
```